# probability of winning a game when your fav player plays in fav game

Tags: probability

Your favourite team in your favourite sport wins 60 percent of their games when your
favourite player plays. When your favourite player is not playing, due to an injury for example,
your favourite team only wins 40 percent of their games. Fortunately, your favourite player is
seldom absent on game day, in fact, over the last two years your favourite player only missed 5
of the 80 games your favourite team played. You did not watch yesterdays game, and consider
watching a recording of it even though your friend spoiled it for you by telling you that your
favourite team won. What is the probability that your favourite player played yesterday?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Please note that on MSE you are expected to show what efforts you have put in and where you are stuck before appropriate help can be given.

Comment: See [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).  What is the source of the problem?  Have you had training in Bayes Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in conditional probability. Denote the events $A=$"your favorite player played", $B=$"your favorite team won". Use the formula

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}$$

and gather the needed probabilities from the text. For $P(B)$ use the law of total probability:

$$P(B)=P(A)P(B|A) + P(A^C)P(B|A^C).$$